# perl referencing dereferencing of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

Consider the following simple piece of code:

```
%hash = ('a'=>1,'b'=>2); 
print $hash{'b'};
print "\n",(\%hash)->{'b'};   #used when hashes are passed by reference
                              #to subroutines
```

The output, as expected, is a pair of 2's. But I was thinking whether $hash{key} is a shorthand for the referencing & dereferencing done as (\%hash)->{key}, or is it an entirely different route to reach the same result.

Please give some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're somewhat different because unlike many other languages, where all complex types are only available as references, Perl have actual plain hash type and separate reference type that can act as proxy to any other type. You can find gory details about this in [perlguts](http://p3rl.org/perlguts).

In the end those two examples both pull data from same storage, of course, but the second invocation is a bit longer because it spends time dutifully creating a reference to plain HV and then dereferencing it back just as you've asked. You can study details on what going under the hood using [`B::Concise`](http://p3rl.org/B%3a%3aConcise) module.

```
%hash = ('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
print $hash{'b'};
print (\%hash)->{'b'};
```

Concise output:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise deref.pl 
t  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 deref.pl:1) v:{ ->3
b     <2> aassign[t3] vKS ->c
-        <1> ex-list lKP ->8
3           <0> pushmark s ->4
4           <$> const[PV "a"] s ->5
5           <$> const[IV 1] s ->6
6           <$> const[PV "b"] s ->7
7           <$> const[IV 2] s ->8
-        <1> ex-list lK ->b
8           <0> pushmark s ->9
a           <1> rv2hv[t2] lKRM*/1 ->b
9              <#> gv[*hash] s ->a
c     <;> nextstate(main 1 deref.pl:2) v:{ ->d
i     <@> print vK ->j
d        <0> pushmark s ->e
h        <2> helem sK/2 ->i
f           <1> rv2hv sKR/1 ->g
e              <#> gv[*hash] s ->f
g           <$> const[PV "b"] s ->h
j     <;> nextstate(main 1 deref.pl:3) v:{ ->k
s     <2> helem vK/2 ->t
q        <1> rv2hv[t7] sKR/1 ->r
p           <@> print sK ->q
k              <0> pushmark s ->l
o              <1> refgen lK/1 ->p
-                 <1> ex-list lKRM ->o
l                    <0> pushmark sRM ->m
n                    <1> rv2hv[t6] lKRM/1 ->o
m                       <#> gv[*hash] s ->n
r        <$> const[PV "b"] s ->s
deref.pl syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

> *But I was thinking whether $hash{key} is a shorthand for the referencing & dereferencing done as (\%hash)->{key}, or is it an entirely different route to reach the same result.*

No, $hash{key} is just a simple access of %hash in the same way that $array[0] would be a simple access of @array. But \%hash is a reference to %hash and so requires dereferencing in order to access it. The syntax `(\%hash)->{key}` would be short for:

```
do { my $temp_ref = \%hash; $temp_ref->{key} }
```

But if you have %hash anyway, $hash{key} works nicely without useless referencing/dereferencing. Hashes and arrays are (generally) passed by reference to subroutines because perl's list flattening makes it difficult to pass more than one otherwise. (One common exception is a function implementing named parameters.)

See `perldoc perreftut` and `perldoc perlref` for a complete explanation of references in perl.

Answer (score 0):

The sigil ($ % @) changes in Perl 5 because it reflects the value being accessed.

```
my @a = (10, 20, 30);  # Whole array
print $a[1];           # Single scalar element of @a
my %h = (a=>1, b=>2);  # Whole hash
print $h{a};           # Single scalar value from %h
```

The reason references all start with "$" is that they are all scalars. Does that help?